# How to iterate a recursive promise

Tags: angularjs, recursion, iteration, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to call a promise function from it's own response in this kind of pattern:

```
f().then(function(response){
    if(response){
        f(response).then(function(response){
            if(response){
                f(response).then.....
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm working with angularjs. Thanks.

P.S.:

This examples are working but the third:

FIRST EXAMPLE: working:

```
var a = ['one','two','four'];

angular.forEach(a, function(number){    
    f(number).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }); 
});
```

SECOND EXAMPLE: working:

```
var a = ['one','two','four'];

angular.forEach(a, function(number){
    f(number).then(function(response){
        if(response){
            f(response).then(function(response2){
                if(response2){
                    f(response2).then(function(response3){
                        console.log(response3); //this is the behaviour I'm trying to automate
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

THIRD EXAMPLE: not working:

```
var a = ['one','two','four'];

angular.forEach(a, function(number){

    var t = '';

    f(number).then(function(response){
        t = response;
        while(t != ''){
            f(t).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                t = response;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

At the end I did so:

```
var a=['one','two','four'];
var simple = function(token){
getasync(a[a.length-1], token).then(function(resptoken){
    console.log(resptoken);
    if(resptoken) 
        simple(resptoken);
    else if (a.length>1){ 
         a.pop() ;
         simple(resptoken);
    }else{
         console.log("theend");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `return` anything (everywhere).

Comment: What does the `forEach` have to do with the recursion?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
function call (response){
   f(response).then(function(response){
      if(response){
         call(response);
      }
   });
}

call(response);
```

if promise was resolved, it will again call itself

Comment: Ok but I can't do. it manually because the number of iterations is unknown.

Comment: Does it work if placed inside a forEach that execute a call(item) for every item in the array?

Comment: What do you mean by iterations?

Comment: Be patient please; give a look to the edited post. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to create a promise where the final resolution depends on one or more fetches from an asynchronous service. If fact you don't know what or how many subsequent fetches you need until you examine data from previous fetches.

This is a job for the much maligned `$q.defer()`. Before you ask [Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern), please bear with me for a moment and examine my example.

In my example, I am going to compute **N factorial**, where the application sends **N** to a server for advice on what to do next. (Compute **N-1 factorial**). The application keeps asking until it receives advice to compute **1 factorial** which it knows.

First step is to create a `$q.defer` and use the promise from it to display the answer.

```
//Function to compute N! asynchronously
//
vm.asyncBangCompute = function(n) {

    var bangDefer = $q.defer();
    var bangPromise = bangDefer.promise;

    //Answer returned here
    //
    bangPromise.then ( function (answer) {
      vm.nAnswer = answer;
    }) .catch (function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

    vm.nBangSoFar = [];
    vm.nCompute = n;
    vm.nAnswer = "PENDING";

    asyncBangResolve(bangDefer, n, 1);
  };
```

Next the resolver function recursively calls the pseudo HTTP service and itself until it resolves an answer.

```
//Recursively call the pseudoHttpService
//
function asyncBangResolve(defer, n, soFar) {
    if (n==1) {
      defer.resolve(soFar);
    } else {
      //push partial results
      vm.nBangSoFar.push(" "+(n*soFar)+" = "+n+"*"+soFar);
      //
      var nextPromise = pseudoHttpService(n,soFar);
      nextPromise.then (function (result) {
        asyncBangResolve(defer,result.data.n,result.data.soFar);
      });
    }
  }
```

The [**DEMO on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zgf1wrmRxvBlC1ASZvbb?p=preview).