# what is the difference between deferred.resolve(data); and deferred.resolve(); in angularJS service calls?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, deferred

I found 2 variation like 
1. deferred.resolve(); 
2. deferred.resolve(data);

after service response. What is the difference between 2. Which one I have to use strictly.

Comment: In one you're passing some data. You should use it when you need to pass some data.

Comment: The first one resolve the promise without sending any data the the resolv function, the second one send `data` to the resolved function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First scenario:

```
function getPromise() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();

    return deferred.promise;
}

getPromise().then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Output "undefined"
    }
);
```

Second scenario:

```
function getPromise() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data = "hello";
    deferred.resolve(data);

    return deferred.promise;
}

getPromise().then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Output "'hello'"
    }
);
```

So it all about on how you resolve the promise, with or without passing information to the function in the resolved promise.

Answer (score 4):

When you call a service, it mean that you're waiting for a server's response.
The response could be a simple success or some data.

```
myServiceFunction = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.post/get(myURL,someData/*not mandatory*/)
          .success(function(response){ // you get into this function when everything goes right
               deferred.resolve(response); //your sending back the server's response to your controller (or whatever has called this function)
        })
         .error(function(response){
              deferred.reject(response); // your also sending back the server's response but using reject means that something gone wrong on server call
    })
    return deferred.promise; // don't forget to send the promise!!
}
```

In the example above I'm sending the response server back to the one which has called the service function.

But if you just need to know that the request succeeded then a simple `deferred.resolve()` is enough (and `deferred.reject()` - to tell that it didn't succeed).

**To make it shorter, here's what you should know:**

- `deferred.resolve()` - means request succeeded
- `deferred.reject()` - request failed
- `deferred.resolve(data)` - means request succeeded and here's some data
- `deferred.reject(data)` - request failed and here;s some data

Hope it's clear enough

Comment: Don't forget to add `return deferred.promise;`

Comment: Also be sure to read [Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Comment: While this will work, I +1 the anti-pattern, my goto reference for deferrals when starting out was this: https://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/%24q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/