# angularjs wait for response from $http

Tags: angularjs

I have the problem that my function doesn't wait for the response of http request and go further. I know that I can use promise to wait but I don't understand the concept.

I have a data service that have all http request :

```
function GetGroupIdFromBakery(bakeryId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $http.get(service.baseUrl + "BakeriesGroup/Bakeries/" + bakeryId)
            .then(function (result) { successCallback(result.data); }, errorCallback);
    }
```

From another service, I call the data service :

```
var hasPermission = function (permission, params) {
            permissionRoute = permission;
            setIdEntity(params);
            for (var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (permissionRoute.Name === permissions[i].Name) {
                    if (permissions[i].Scope == "System")
                        return true;
                    else if (permissions[i].Scope == permissionRoute.Scope && permissions[i].IdEntity == permissionRoute.IdEntity) 
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }



var setIdEntity = function (params) {
            if (permissionRoute.Scope == "Bakery")
                permissionRoute.IdEntity = parseInt(params.bakeryId);
            else if (permissionRoute.Scope == "Group") {
                if (params.bakeriesGroupId)
                    permissionRoute.IdEntity = parseInt(params.bakeriesGroupId);
                else {
                    getGroupOfBakery(parseInt(params.bakeryId));   
                }

                console.log(permissionRoute.IdEntity);
            }
        }

var getGroupOfBakery = function (bakeryId) {
            DataService.GetGroupIdFromBakery(bakeryId, function (groupId) {
                permissionRoute.IdEntity = groupId;
            }, function (error) {
                console.error("something went wrong while getting bakery");
                alert("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la récupération de la boulangerie");
            });

        }
```

I must wait for the response of DataService.GetGroupIdFromBakery(). With this code, permission.EntityId is undefined when I call getGroupByBakery().

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use promises.

Comment: Is it possible to use callback?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but, to me, a promise ***is*** a callback. I am sure that they are the same under the hood. Anyway, you say "`I know that I can use promise to wait but I don't understand the concept`"; nor did i at first, then I started thinking of them as fucntionallly identical, and it clciked.  Purists may well disagree ;-) but, if it helps you, think of pronises as callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a watcher to your response data. I think it is `EntityId`  in your case.
It get executed as soon as your `EntityId` changes. After getting the response data you can call the function, this time `EntityId` will not be `undefined`.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
            return EntityId  
        }, function (newEntityId) {
            if(newEntityId != undefined {
                // now you can call your function
             }
            }
        }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you have to use promises, because $http module is asynchronus. I built a service for that:

```
.service('RequestService', function($q, $http){
  return {
    call: function(htmlOptions){
      var d = $q.defer();
      var promise = d.promise;
      $http(htmlOptions)
        .then(function(response){
          d.resolve(response.data);
         }, function(response){
          d.reject(response.data);
        });
      promise.success = function(fn) {
       promise.then(fn);
        return promise;
      };
      promise.error = function(fn) {
       promise.then(null, fn);
       return promise;
      };
      return promise;
    }
  }
})
```

And then:

```
RequestService.call({
   method: 'POST' //GET, DELETE ...
   data: data,
   url: 'http://someurl.com/'
  });
```

Comment: Just be aware, this is the deferred promise antipattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757201/4735725

Answer (score 0):

you should use defer.
create a new defer object in GetGroupIdFromBakery method,in success part resolve the defer and in failed part reject it, and return the promise of defer at the end.

```
function GetGroupIdFromBakery(bakeryId, successCallback, errorCallback, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get(service.baseUrl + "BakeriesGroup/Bakeries/" + bakeryId)
        .then(function (result) { 
           successCallback(result.data);
              defer.resolve(result.data); 
           }, function(){
              defer.reject(); 
           });
   return defer.promise;
}
```

This successfully return you a promise that you can call with .then() and receive as a value in the service where you need to have the data of GetGroupIdFromBakery.

```
getGroupOfBakery(parseInt(params.bakeryId), $q).then(function(data){
    // here you have data
})
```

Be aware you should inject $q, here I supposed that we have $q in service and I passed it to method.