# service gets URL for $http API request from controller - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a service that grabs info from an API but only after clicking an HTML element.

```
"freegeoip.net/json/" + ip_address
```

**The problem is, my service and URL above is being called before the click occurs.**

```
app.service("ips", function ($http, $q)
{
    // Grab json
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://www.freegeoip.net/json/" + ip_address).then(function (data)
    {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getItems = function ()
    {
        console.log(deferred.promise);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

Can someone show me I can define this variable ip_address later in a click?

///Inside the controller

```
promise.then(function (data)
{
    $scope.items = data.data.items;
});
$scope.defineIP= function(item)
{
   ip_address = "212.38.168.60"
   return ip_address;
}
```

The problem here is that I have no clue how to take this value i defined for ip_address and inject it into the service.

Comment: are you calling getItems Method in controller on click of some element ?
post the code related to it !

Comment: the getItems method is being called immediately when the controller is initialized. If you have a smarter way of doing this, i'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code should go like this.

```
app.service("ips", function ($http) {
    this.getItems = function (ip_address) {
       return  $http.get("freegeoip.net/json/" + ip_address)
    }
});
```

and in controller :

```
$scope.defineIP= function(){
   var ip_address = "212.38.168.60"
   ips.getItems(ip_address).then(function(response){
     console.log(response);
   }) 
}
```

Dont forget to add "ips" as DI in controller.

As you want to grab info on click of HTML element then you should call like below:

```
 <button ngClick="defineIP()">Click Here</button>
```

You dont need to inject $q in service as $http returns you the Promise Object so that you can use .then() method directly in controller

Comment: This is also 100% correct and works. I am torn as to which Answer I should give the Green Check to. Who's answer is more efficient?

Comment: your choice ... :)
however never use $q in $http (may be sometimes in some cases you may need to use $q); it actually returns promise

Answer (score 0):

The $http request will be called once u inject the service. So you should be called like this.

```
app.service("ips", function ($http, $q)
{
    // Grab json    

    this.getItems = function (ip_address)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("freegeoip.net/json/" + ip_address).then(function (data)
        {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

In controller:

```
var promise = ipsService.getItems(ip_address);
```

Comment: And then in the controller, which has the service ips, do I call this.getItems(someIPstring)?

Comment: Your answer as well Rahul's are correct but I can only give one green check. Who's is more efficient?

Comment: This is a $q.defer anti-pattern. The promise hangs if the $http request is rejected. See [Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).