# How to have promise for the multiple functions in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

*Code explanation:*

If internet is available it will sync the unsynced data from the different tables based on different methods.But, I would like to know how to add promise for these different functions.The logic which I used in making all the functions to start simultaneously but, I would like to start function2 based on the success of function1 and repeat the same process can anyone tell me how to do it.

```
function syncApp () {
  $log.log('offlineOnlineSync got called');

  Contact.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('Contact sync got called', resp);

    WorkerGroup.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
      $log.log('WorkerGroup sync got called', resp);

      Category.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
        $log.log('Category sync got called', resp);

        Vehicle.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
          $log.log('Vehicle sync got called', resp);

          Daybook.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
            $log.log('Daybook sync got called', resp);
          }, CommonService.errorHandler);

        }, CommonService.errorHandler);

      }, CommonService.errorHandler);

    }, CommonService.errorHandler);

  }, CommonService.errorHandler);
}
```

In the first method the process which takes place is this but before completing the above process the second method gets called.

```
    prom = DB.update('contacts', servResp, 'id', key)
      .then(function () {
        if (servResp.type === 'Worker') {
            WorkerGroup.checkGroupForTempIds(key, servResp.id)
             .then(function (resp) {
                  $log.log('Response in contact service', resp);
            }, function (err) {
                  $log.log('err: ', err);
            });
        } // fix me // not needed
    }, function (err) {
          $log.log('err: ', err);
    });

    $log.log('serverresponseid', servResp.id);
    $log.log('key', key);
    var daybook_updatequery = 'UPDATE daybook SET contact_id = ? WHERE contact_id = ?';

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(Database.db, daybook_updatequery, [servResp.id, key])
      .then(function (resp) {
        $log.log('response', resp);
        defer.resolve('success');
    }, function (err) {
        q.reject(err);
        $log.log(err);
    });

    proms.push(prom);
});
$q.all(proms).then(function () {
    defer.resolve('success');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: What is the problem with your example code besides being ugly? Does it work?

Comment: @TamasHegedus Lol.

Comment: Try to [chain your promises](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/), or use `$q.all()`

Comment: @arqam OP asked "how to do it", not "how to do it better". I see a chance that there is some error in the current approach (an error in one of the called services for example) but the real problem has not been stated due to miscommunication.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is wrong with the `getAllProms` function because parts of it are missing. On first observation, it fails to use [return statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) in the `.then` handler functions and it uses broken [$q.defer anti-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Comment: Your edit is incomplete. Is `prom` a global variable? What is `defer`? What is `q`? (`q` is not the same as `$q`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have parent promises wait for completion of chained promises, it is important to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the chained promise to the parent `.then` handler function:

```
function getProm(servResp, key) {
    ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ DB.update('contacts', servResp, 'id', key)
      .then(function () {
        if (servResp.type === 'Worker') {
            ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ WorkerGroup.checkGroupForTempIds(key, servResp.id)
             .then(function (resp) {
                  $log.log('Response in contact service', resp);
                  ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟  resp;
            }, function (err) {
                  $log.log('err: ', err);
                  //IMPORTANT
                  throw err;
            });
        } else {
            ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ "something";
        };
    }, function (err) {
          $log.log('err: ', err);
          //IMPORTANT
          throw err;
    });
}
```

Also to avoid **converting** rejected promises to fulfilled promises, it is important to use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in the rejection handler function.

When a `.then` method handler function omits a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), the method returns a new promise that resolves `undefined` and that promise does not wait for any asychronous operations started in that handler function.

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the promises, so you only need one error handler:

```
function syncApp () {
  $log.log('offlineOnlineSync got called');
  return Contact.syncApp().then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('Contact sync got called', resp);
    return WorkerGroup.syncApp();
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('WorkerGroup sync got called', resp);
    return Category.syncApp();
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('Category sync got called', resp);
    return Vehicle.syncApp();
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('Vehicle sync got called', resp);
    return Daybook.syncApp();
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('Daybook sync got called', resp);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    CommonService.errorHandler(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: i have tried with the above code but before completing the task of first method the second one gets started