# jQuery dependent AJAX call promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have 2 async calls

```js
function async1() {
  return $j.post('/call1', JSON.stringify({
    id: my_id
  }), function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
      // resolve
    } else {
      // reject
    }
  });
}

function async2() {
  return $j.post('/call2', JSON.stringify({
    id: my_id
  }), function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
      // resolve
    } else {
      // reject
    }
  });
}
```

From a `main()` function I need to call `async1()` first and if it is successful, `async2()` will be called.

I intend to return a promise from `main()`. My main concern is that I need to explicitly resolve or reject according to the responses. Can anyone show me how to go about it using promises / deferred?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? v1, v2, v3?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using v1

Comment: And you want to return a native Promise? Or a jQuery Deferred?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder jQuery Promise

Answer (score 0):

Could go like this:

```js
function async1() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => $j.post(
      '/call1',
      JSON.stringify({
        id: my_id
      }),
      function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
          resolve( /*pass whatever*/ )
        } else {
          reject( /*pass whatever*/ )
        }
      });
  }
}

function async2() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => $j.post(
      '/call2',
      JSON.stringify({
        id: my_id
      }),
      function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
          resolve( /*pass whatever*/ );
        } else {
          reject( /*pass whatever*/ )
        }
      });
  }
}

function main() {
  async1().then(async2).then((success) => console.log(success)).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not **useful** answers, and if you're going to use `new Promise` when you already have a thenable, you'll need to explain why it's better than using the thenable.

Comment: 1. deferreds are (antipattern)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern], jquery promise implementation is diverging from the standards and dying out. 2. Regarding code dump, generally I agree, but if the code is self explicative I'd still be fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

You call async1() first, and at the successful response of async1() you do async2() function. Like this:

```
function async1() {

  return $j.post(
        '/call1',
        JSON.stringify({id: my_id}),
        async2(response)    // <-- Replace function(response){} to this.
  });

}
```

And then on async2 function:

```
function async2(dataAsync1) {
  var data = dataAsync1;  //Response from previews Ajax call...
                          //TODO: Handle this
  return $j.post(
    '/call2',
    JSON.stringify({id: my_id}),
    function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            // resolve
        }
        else {
            // reject
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My main concern is , i need to explicitly resolve or reject according to the responses.

Good concern: No, you don't. Just use the results you're given by the promise from jQuery's `post`.

Since you're using jQuery v1.x, I'll just note that its `Deferred` object is **not** Promises/A+ compliant. You may or may not care about that. I'll assume you're using v1.8 or later, though.

So if you're okay with using jQuery's non-Promises/A+-compliant Deferred and promise, then just return the result of `post`.

I'll stick with ES5 syntax, since you're using jQuery v1.x and I'm guessing you're not transpiling, etc.

```
function async1(my_id/* I assume it's a parameter?*/) {
    return $j.post(
        '/call1',
        JSON.stringify({id: my_id})
    );
}

function async2(my_id/* I assume it's a parameter?*/) {
    return $j.post(
        '/call2',
        JSON.stringify({id: my_id})
    );
}
```

...and in `main`, use those "promises":

```
function main(some_id) {
    return async1(some_id).then(function(result1) {
        return async2(some_id).then(function(result2) {
            return [result1, result2];
        });
    });
}
```

That example has `main` returning a promise of an array, where the first entry in the array will be the result from `async1` and the second is the result from `async2` (or where it rejects because one of them failed). You can tweak that as you like, though, by changing the return in the second `then` handler.

**If** you want `main` to return a native promise instead (using a polyfill if necessary), I'd probably convert to native promises early by giving myself a wrapper for `post` that provides a native promise:

```
function postPromise() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $j.post.apply($j, args)
            .done(resolve)
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown) {
                    reject(errorThrown);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error(textStatus)); // or whatever
                }
            });
    });
}
```

then

```
function async1(my_id/* I assume it's a parameter?*/) {
    return postPromise(
        '/call1',
        JSON.stringify({id: my_id})
    );
}

function async2(my_id/* I assume it's a parameter?*/) {
    return postPromise(
        '/call2',
        JSON.stringify({id: my_id})
    );
}
```

...and in `main`, use those "promises":

```
function main() {
    return async1("the-id").then(function(result1) {
        return async2("the-id").then(function(result2) {
            return [result1, result2];
        });
    });
}
```

That has the advantage (?) of working with jQuery < v1.8.

Comment: Basically 'async1' can succesfully complete and according to the value of certain data got as response , i need to reject or resolve . How is that possible here?

Comment: @Vivek: Sorry, I'm afraid that's not really clear. Do you want to call `async2` even if `async1` fails? *Only* when it fails? Only when it succeeds?

Comment: Only when async1 succeeds should async2 be called. The caveat here is the success condition. If i got succesful response say `responseData` and if `responseData.someVariable == false` , then async2 should not be called.

Comment: @Vivek: Just put that condition inside the `then` handler on the call from `async`, and either return something else or return the result of calling `async2`.