# how to cover this.service in jasmine of my angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How to cover the highlighted code

```
genericFunctionsService.getConfigDetails().then((config) => {

        let navigationURL = genericFunctionsService.replacePlaceHolders(config.data.navigationUrl, {
            '{edition}': editionObject.editionCode,
            '{language}': editionObject.editionLanguage
        });
         *this.getNavigationItemsFromService(navigationURL).then(( navigationData ) => {
            let tempNavItem = this.filterNavigationItems(navigationData.data, editionObject);
            deferred.resolve(tempNavItem);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });*
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

---

```
this.getNavigationItemsFromService(navigationURL)
  .then(( navigationData ) => {
    let tempNavItem = this.filterNavigationItems(navigationData.data, editionObject);
    deferred.resolve(tempNavItem); 
}).catch(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error); 
});
```

After dot then it is showing me orange color which is not covered, i am not able to cover this with my unit testing

Comment: *this.getNavigationItemsFromService(navigationURL).then(( navigationData ) => {
                let tempNavItem = this.filterNavigationItems(navigationData.data, editionObject);
                deferred.resolve(tempNavItem);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });*    
After then it is showing me orange color which is covered, i am not able to cover this with my unit testing

Comment: Avoid using a [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Comment: @georgeawg Yes, but in my case, how to change deferred anti Pattern, because I need tempNavItem from navigationData.data, plz help

Answer (score 0):

> how to change deferred anti Pattern, because I need tempNavItem from navigationData.data, plz help

```
genericFunctionsService.getConfigDetails()
  .then((config) => {  
    let navigationURL = genericFunctionsService.replacePlaceHolders(config.data.navigationUrl, {
        '{edition}': editionObject.editionCode,
        '{language}': editionObject.editionLanguage
    });
    var promise = this.getNavigationItemsFromService(navigationURL)
      .then(( navigationData ) => {
        let tempNavItem = this.filterNavigationItems(navigationData.data, editionObject);
        return tempNavItem;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
    return promise;
});
```

The `.then` method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)).

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).