# Service using $http not returning new data

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

### AngularJS ng-repeat not changing when array changes

I have a controller:

```
  <section data-ng-controller="FilmController">
    <article data-ng-view></article>
  </section>
```

This is its controller:

```
.controller('FilmController',
      [
        '$scope',
        'dataService',
        '$routeParams',
        function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams) {
          var getFilms = function(searchterm, category, page){
            dataService.getFilms(searchterm, category, page).then(
              function(response){
                $scope.films = [];
                $scope.films = response.data;
                let pageLinks = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < response.data[10][0]; i += 10) {
                  pageLinks.push({
                    pageLink: "/wai/wai-assignment/#/films?searchterm=" + searchterm + "&category=" + category + "&page=" + i/10,
                    pageNum: i/10
                  })
                }
                $scope.pageLinks = pageLinks;
                console.log(pageLinks);
              },
              function(err){
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data' + err;
              },
              function(notify){
                console.log(notify);
              }
            );
          }

          if ($routeParams && ($routeParams.searchterm || $routeParams.category)){
            getFilms($routeParams.searchterm, $routeParams.category, $routeParams.page);
          } else {
            getFilms('','',$routeParams.page);
          }
        }
      ]);
```

These are the routes:

```
app.config(
        [
            '$routeProvider',

            function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/films', {
                        templateUrl: 'js/partials/films.html',
                        controller: 'FilmController'
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            }
        ]
    );
```

Here is the template:

```
<section>
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="film in films">
      <td>{{film.title}}</td>
      <td>{{film.name}}</td>
      <td>{{film.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a data-ng-repeat="pageLink in pageLinks" ng-href="{{pageLink.pageLink}}">
    {{pageLink.pageNum}}
  </a>
</section>
```

When i access `films?searchterm=example&category=example&page=1`

It shows films with the category and search criteria from a database. When i click a link to go to a different `page`, it just grabs data from an SQL statement with a different `OFFSET`, but the `ng-repeat` doesn't update with it.

I know why this happens, something to do with scopes, but i can't work out how to fix it. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

```
angular.module('filmDirectoryApp')
    .service('dataService',
        [
          '$q',
          '$http',
          function ($q, $http) {
            var urlBase = 'server/';
            var defer = $q.defer();
            this.getFilms = function (searchterm, category, page) {
              $http.get(urlBase + 'getfilms.php?searchterm=' + searchterm + '&category=' + category + '&page=' + page)
                .success(function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  defer.resolve({
                      data: response
                  });
                })
                .error(function (err) {
                    defer.reject(err);
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
          }
        ]
      );
```

Comment: @dota2pro `ng-repeat='film in films'` is the `ng-repeat` in question and it is version 1.5.6

Comment: @dota2pro It is saying that it is changed but it isn't changing. I think the database request isn't working correctly. I'll see if i can get that fixed.

Comment: @dota2pro No that section is just to load the page links. It's not related i don't think.

Comment: So if i `console.log(response)` in the dataService, it returns the correct data. If i return the data that has supposedly been sent to the controller from that dataService then it logs the wrong data.

Comment: Please check if you get correct $scope.films value thanks

Comment: We need to see the code for the `dataService`. Two possibilities: it uses a [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern) that is coded incorrectly, or it returns ES6 promises  or some other type of promise that is not integrated with the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @georgeawg I forgot to add the dataService earlier. I added it as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The code uses a [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern) that is written incorrectly. The `$q.defer` only resolves once. Subsequent calls to `defer.resolve` are ignored. This is the way promises work.

In addition the [`.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and have been removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

The solution is to avoid the deferred anti-pattern and use the `.then` and `.catch` methods.

```
angular.module('filmDirectoryApp')
.service('dataService',
    [
      '$http',
      function ($http) {
        var urlBase = 'server/';
        this.getFilms = function (searchterm, category, page) {
          var params = {
              "searchterm": searchterm,
              "category"  : category,
              "page"      : page
          };
          var config = { "params": params };    
          return $http.get(urlBase + 'getfilms.php', config)
            .then(function (response) {
              var data = response.data;
              console.log(data);
              return data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.log(err)
              throw err;
            });
        }
      }
    ]
);
```

The $http service deprecated custom callback methods - `.success()` and `.error()` - have been removed. You can use the standard `.then()`/`.catch()` promise methods instead, but note that the method signatures and return values are different.

The `.then` method returns a *new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)
- [Is this a deferred anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern)
- [Why were `.success` and `error` removed from the $http service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)

Comment: Thanks alot for this. The code you showed is identical to my previous code. How would i write a .then.catch variant of it?