# POST request to PHP does not retrieve any data when using a form instead of angular http client

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using angular http client to interact with database and everything works but when I am trying to POST data to the same link using a form, I get that the data is undefined.

I was trying to encode, decode values as I know that before making any POST request and sending data, I need to perform angular.toJSON method, but that did not work.

This is my index.php where I receive a POST request from the form.

```
if (empty($action)) {
    if ((($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) && 
             (strpos($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'], 'application/json') !== false)) {

        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        $action = isset($input['action']) ? $input['action'] : null;
        $subject = isset($input['subject']) ? $input['subject'] : null;
        $data = isset($input['data']) ? $input['data'] : null;
    }

case 'createNote':
        // if I die() here, it prints the die()
        if(!empty($data)) {
            // if I die() here, $data is undefined.
            $data = json_decode($data);

            $user = $data[0];
            $comment = $data[1];
            $film_id = $data[2];
            $lastupdated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


            $sql = "INSERT INTO nfc_note (user, film_id, comment, lastupdated) 
                    VALUES (:user, :film_id, :comment, :lastupdated)";
        }
        break;
```

My form that I use to send POST request

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="note">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo "['username','content', 1]"; ?>">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

As mentioned above, it works when I use angular's http and pass parameters like this:

```
this.createNote = function (data) {

    var defer = $q.defer(),
    data = {
        action: "create",
        subject: "note",
        data: angular.toJson(data)
    };
    $http
        .post(urlBase, data)
        .success(function (response) {
            defer.resolve({
                data: response.data
            });
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

Does not work when I use a form. Any suggestions or mistakes that I am not aware of?

Comment: Avoid the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). Also the `.success` method has been [removed from AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code is expecting Json formatted data, and it is not getting that. It is because the HTML Form sends out POST data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To support both data formats, you need to build a logic on your PHP code to detect either format. The data format is mentioned in the HTTP header where you can check that. Look for `Content-Type`. For POST data coming for your HTML form, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and for the Json it should be `application/json`.

You can read the form values in PHP by using `$_POST[<form_parameter>]`. In your case `$_POST['data']`. To make your HTML form a bit simpler you can also split the `data` array into their own inputs in the form.

See this for some more info: https://www.smtpeter.com/en/documentation/json-vs-post

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem something like 
"POST request to PHP does not retrieve any data when using a form instead of angular http client".
Normally use stream php to detect data from Angular to PHP

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But when scan the code with fortify it detect the xss vulnerability and I must change the methods.

Solved this problem in this way, I hope that help someone. :-)

ANGULAR:

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/saveTemplateEmail',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
data: {templateEmail:$scope.selectedTipology}}).then(function (response) {.....}
```

PHP:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_val = json_decode($data, true);
```

I changed it to the following

ANGULAR:

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/saveTemplateEmail',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
data: jQuery.param({templateEmail:$scope.selectedTipology})}).then(function (response) {.....}
```

PHP:

```
$post_val = $_POST;
```