# deffer.promise result wont display in typehead using service

Tags: angularjs, promise, typehead

i am using angularjs 1.7 and i am trying to display the result of the function using service in the typhead

```
<input type="text" id="oppId" name="oppId" aria-label="oppId"
       ng-model="oppId"
       typeahead="item for item in commonService.oppIdTypeAhead($viewValue) | limitTo:10"
       ng-blur="checkAndValidate($event)">
```

```
oppIdTypeAhead: function (val) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var config = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                url: constants.oppPickup,
                params: {
                    oppID: val
                },
                timeout: this._getCanceler('OppTypeAhead')
            };

            $http(config).then(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data.data);
            }).catch(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (status === 0 && data === null) {
                    deferred.reject('canceled');
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                }
            });
            console.log(deferred.promise);
            return deferred.promise;
```

this is the result returned by promise

[image]

it should display the list of results
but then it has an exception of Object doesn't support property or method 'success'

Comment: can u share `controller` code  ?  i cant find `success` in your existing question so I cant debug it.  show me the code which is throwing that error and the screenshot of the code please

Comment: Avoid the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). Also the signature of the `.catch` method is wrong. See [why was the `.success` method removed from AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).