# Download file with filesaver.js with angularJS from web api response c#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, pdf, filesaver.js

Im using the filesaver js library for download files... i'm generating a endpoint with web api that returns my file from base64 but i don't know how to return base64 as Blob for download with filesaver....

- Im tried make differents responses types
- try to understand how to does it works the Blob data

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(int id)
{
   string mybase64file = GetBase64File(id)
   byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(mybase64file );

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);


  HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
  result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
  result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "someFileName.pdf";
  result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

   return result;
}
```

AngularJS service:

```
function download() {
  var deferred = $q.defer()
  $http.get('url', {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
    }, 
    responseType: 'blob'
  })
    .success(function (response) {
      saveAs(response, 'someName.pdf') 
    })
    .error(function (err) {
      deferred.reject(err)
    })

  return deferred.promise
}
```

When the angularjs service recieve to response, im call the "saveAs" function, but this generate the next error:

> "angular.min.js:118 TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

Comment: You will get better stack traces if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339). Avoid using the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Answer (score 0):

To return a file from ASP MVC CORE, use:

```
return File(stream, "application/octet-stream");
return FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
return PhysicalFileResult("path to file", "application/octet-stream");
```

With that, you dont even need filesaver js library, the file will download automatically once that link is requested.

One more thing: You cant download a file with Ajax (`....$http.get('url', {....`)!

You could use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) do get the blob, see implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/3563013

To address the specific error ( `"angular.min.js:118 TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided."` ), its possible [window.URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is not supported in the browser you are using to test.